# Ratio known and Amount needed known

Tags: functions, ratio

You have a a recipe for the perfect orange juice, it is:

26 parts Water to 1 Part Orange Juice **(26:1)**.

However overall you only want 20ml of mixed liquid (orange juice and water combined).

What calculation do you carry out in a function/logic format that so that any number can be replaced eg:

```
Ratio : x : y
Required: z
```

Comment: Welcome to this site! This site is for posting your mathematical questions to get answers, not for posting your mathematical tasks (or assignments) to have someone do them for you. What have you tried? What is it that you don't understand? Once this is clear to you, you can ask a precise question.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $26$ parts Water to $1$ part Orange Juice make how many parts of mixed liquid?
- If $x$ parts mixed liquid is $20$ml then how much liquid is in each part?